# Adding values in one list and subtracting it with values in other list

Tags: java, excel, apache

1. I have an excel sheet from which I'm accessing the data and using in java to do some validation
2. So far the problem is, excel has one column with 200+ rows and positive and negative values in it are like, [EXCEL IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBuNz.png)
3. I'm trying to write to code where I can delete the row value where it can be subtracted with the negative one.
4. Here the problem is, if you look at the excel sheet, the values 2,3,5 must be added inorder to get subtracted with the -8 
   so that I get a zero.
5. I don't know how to add those values three values or even more can be there, if we suppose values are 1,2,2,3 and a -8
6. So far I was able to achieve the functionality below where it adds upto two values and in the positive list and then subtracts 
   it with a matching negative value in the negative list and giving me the end result zero.
7. So my request is to let me know how to achieve the similar functionality in case there are more than two values which can be added
8. Hope you could help! Thanks!

---

Here's the pseudo code.

1) one list for negative numbers and sorted

2) one list for postivie numbers and sorted

3)iterate and start with the maximum number in negative list

4) check the index of the equal or lesser number in the positive list

5) iterate the positive list using from this index:

```
 a) if current positive number 
    1) equal to negative number - nullify and put them in map, go to next negative number
    2) else if less than negative number - 
    i) get the difference of this positive number and the negative number 
    ii) create a variable for this difference and put it in while loop
    iii) search for the index of the number equal to or lesser to this difference.
    iv) get the second positive number and if is 
        a) equal to difference, nullify all by updatng index of the negative and two positives numbers as NA
               update difference to 0 and exit while and go to next negative number
        b) else if the second positive number is less than the difference, sum the two numbers and negative number
           and get the difference and update the difference variable with this new value and iterate while loop
        c) if there is no lesser or mathcing number equal to difference, 
           come out of while and pick the next element in positive list as done in step (v) and get next number
           and repeat further.
```

See if you can help me now...

Comment: What is the end objective? You question is lengthy and not clear.What you want to achieve with this?

Comment: This is a very bad implementation. you are using 4 nested loops, definitely not accepted. Can you please help us with pseudo code, I will help you with the java code.

Comment: The data is  present in the excel sheet column & has 200+ rows and filled with these type of values, so I took positive in one list and negative in another. I'm trying to make as many rows as zero. Wherever the calculation is possible. @ProgrammerBoy

Comment: I know but I couldn't find any alternate way to do it, so far it works fine. Please try to make changes if you could. @SaurabhJhunjhunwala

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I have updated a pseudo code. Look if you can help me..